# how to add buttons dynamically in Alert Box in Android

Tags: android, button, dynamic, android-alertdialog

I am developing android application in which for validations, it displays messages with alert box. I wanted to add buttons dynamically according to certain conditions. I like ask how to do this? I searched on Google, but couldn't find any suitable solutions.

Any Suggestions are helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Show us how u are doing it now.

Comment: Right now i am doing with regular alert box. but for some conditions i need one button like "OK", but for some conditions i need alert box with "ok" And "Cancel" button. I made one createAlerBox method which I am calling from my respective conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer, I used Command Design pattern with help of CommandWrapper.

The following link elaborate more precisely. [link](https://developmentality.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/android-dialog-box-tutorial/)

Thank you for everyone for their suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DialogFragment to acheive it.
Create your own dialog view and inflate it in the onCreateView() of the dialog fragment.

Comment: Good suggestion Gogu but, i am developing application in API level 7 and as DialogFragment supports from API level 11. Is there anything I can do to work this in API level 7 ?

Comment: Dialog fragments are supported with the help of compatibility package

Answer (score 0):

if you know the possible buttons that could be displayed:

- add them to your layout
- use the visibility attributes to show or hide it them, according to your conditions. ([How To](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29))