# Custom button in AlertDialog programmatically

Tags: java, android

After lots of research on stackoverflow and google, I have really found no issue to my problem.
Well, I'd like to create a button with height = 50 and width = 50 on top right of my dialog. 
Well, I can set height without problem, but width doesn't work.
I tried with creating a linearLayout, but params never took in consideration. 
Here is my code (height is sets properly) :

```
private void hello(){
    Button button = new Button(this);

    button.setMinimumWidth(0);
    button.setWidth(50);
    button.setMinimumHeight(0);
    button.setHeight(50);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            sayHello();
        }
    });

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
            .setTitle("Hello world")
            .setView(button)
            .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click !", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    hello();
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

I tried with :

```
        button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50));
```

Without any success.

And with :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rlp.height = 50;
    rlp.width = 50;

    button.setText("i");
    button.setLayoutParams(rlp);
```

And doesn't work either...

I really don't understand what's happening, can you try help me please?

I precise, I don't have any xml, it's only in java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add buttons dynamically in Alert Box in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607236/how-to-add-buttons-dynamically-in-alert-box-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to create my own alert dialog to customize it as I wish. 
I had to create a xml file and used an inflater. The reason why setHeight works and not setWidth will forever stays a mystery...

Thank's for your help anyway